# AMS inequalities: a variant of \gtrsim and \lesssim

Tags: fonts, amsmath

I'm searching a variant of Mathematical symbols using `amsmath` for two specific command. It is known that for AMS symbols `\gtrsim` and `\lesssim` produces these fonts:

[image]

I would have instead a little variant that I have not found on [symbols-a4.pdf](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).
The symbol is this (for `\lessim`):

[image: enter code here]

Similarly I would like to have the same symbol for `\gtrsim`. How can you help me using only `pdflatex`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think Unicode has a separate symbol which means that most fonts will only have one although there may be a font that uses a sloping `~` for U+2272, I do not know of one though.

Comment: I have appreciated often (or almost) your suggestions :-). I have voted positive your comment and I thank you always for the time that you dedicate to me.

Comment: I don't think your readers would understand the symbol.

Comment: @egreg The readers of my book? But mathematically "speaking" the symbol at the university I used it often.

Comment: When writing ≤ by hand, I tend to use the slanted version, but I find that the slanted version in print is awful. Slanting the `\sim` is even worse, in my opinion.

Comment: @egreg This time I accept your advice. :-) I honestly thought that the symbol that I would like to have had existed. There are an infinite number of symbols, the ones I like do not exist or are ugly to see.

Comment: It is funny.  Just yesterday, I was searching for a symbol that meant "just a teeny bit less than" and was thinking along the lines of `\lesssym`.  However, a search of the internet revealed that there was no standard notation for the concept (unlike `<<` meaning "a whole lot less than").

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes It means that I have the crystal ball in my house to read in your mind. I am writing a book together with a prof. and I would like to do it very well in memory for my beloved and dear father who is not close to me and who I cry, although almost two years have passed, always.

Comment: I too lost my father in recent years (2012 for me).  I too miss him dearly.  At the end of my profile, https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/25858/steven-b-segletes?tab=profile, there are some links about him.  I learned some awesome secrets about his young professional life, only in the last year of his life (50 years after the fact).  I am so glad I had the chance to share these things with him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here I introduce `\varlesssim` and `\vargtrsim`.  Unlike their un-var'ed counterparts, I here preserve the math axis of `<` and `>` for these new symbols, rather than raising them up real high.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,stackengine,graphicx}
\newcommand\varlesssim{\mathrel{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{-.4ex}{<}{\rotatebox{-25}{$\sim$}}{U}{r}{F}{T}{S}}}}
\newcommand\vargtrsim{\mathrel{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{-.4ex}{>}{\rotatebox{25}{$\sim$}}{U}{l}{F}{T}{S}}}}
\begin{document}
\[
x \lesssim y \gtrsim z <p > q \sim r
\]
\[
x \varlesssim y < z
\]
\[
x \vargtrsim y > z
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

For a version that works across math styles, mix in `scalerel`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,stackengine,graphicx,scalerel}
\newcommand\varlesssim{\mathrel{\ensurestackMath{\ThisStyle{%
  \stackengine{-.4\LMex}{\SavedStyle<}{%
    \rotatebox{-25}{$\SavedStyle\sim$}}{U}{r}{F}{T}{S}}}}}
\newcommand\vargtrsim{\mathrel{\ensurestackMath{\ThisStyle{%
  \stackengine{-.4\LMex}{\SavedStyle>}{%
    \rotatebox{25}{$\SavedStyle\sim$}}{U}{l}{F}{T}{S}}}}}
\begin{document}
\[
x \lesssim y \gtrsim z <p > q \sim r
\]
\[
x \varlesssim y < z
\]
\[
x \vargtrsim y > z
\]
\[
\scriptstyle x \varlesssim y < z
\]
\[
\scriptstyle x \vargtrsim y > z
\]
\[
\scriptscriptstyle x \varlesssim y < z
\]
\[
\scriptscriptstyle x \vargtrsim y > z
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**FOLLOW UP**

The OP asked for a variation on my original answer.  It wasn't totally clear all the aspects of the request, but two things noted were smaller `\sim` size and closer proximity between the two components of the composite symbol.

If it is still not quite to the OP's taste, I can describe what parameters change what.  The `\scalebox` 1st argument determines the scale of the `\sim`, the `-.45\LMex` affects the vertical gap between the two base symbols (where `\LMex` is a measure of `ex` that scales smaller with the smaller math sizes, and the +/-`25` governs the rotation of the `\sim`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,scalerel}
\newcommand\scalesim{\scalebox{.8}{$\SavedStyle\sim$}}
\newcommand\varlesssim{\mathrel{\ensurestackMath{\ThisStyle{%
  \stackengine{-.45\LMex}{\SavedStyle<}{%
    \rotatebox{-25}{\scalesim}}{U}{l}{F}{T}{S}}}}}
\newcommand\vargtrsim{\mathrel{\ensurestackMath{\ThisStyle{%
  \stackengine{-.45\LMex}{\SavedStyle>}{%
    \rotatebox{25}{\scalesim}}{U}{r}{F}{T}{S}}}}}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\Centerstack{x \varlesssim y < z\\
             x \vargtrsim y > z}
\]
\[
\Centerstack{\scriptstyle x \varlesssim y < z\\
             \scriptstyle x \vargtrsim y > z}
\]
\[
\Centerstack{\scriptscriptstyle x \varlesssim y < z\\
             \scriptscriptstyle x \vargtrsim y > z}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Steven you are great!!!! Could you make a slight change? Decrease the size of the `\sim` command, and bring it slightly closer to the `>` or `<` symbol towards the peak so that the sine wave tail ends with the amplitude of the major or minor symbol? Thank you very much and I hope that Google translator has translated correctly.

Comment: @Sebastiano  I understood some of your request, but not so much regarding "peak", "amplitude", and "tail ends".   I provided an edit I hope helps.